# Center AddThis Inline Follow Buttons div

Tags: html, css, addthis, squarespace

I am trying to center the AddThis inline follow buttons. By default they left align.

The code for the follow buttons is:

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_inline_follow_toolbox"></div>
```

I tried adding them within a div like so:

```
<div class="center_aift">
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_inline_follow_toolbox"></div>
</div>
```

I added the following CSS but it made no difference, they still align to the left.

```
.center_aift {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am using SquareSpace with a custom code block but do not think that is the problem.

Comment: By default, the buttons are set to `display: inline-block;`. The selector from the widget is `.at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn`. Your `text-align: center;` [centers them fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gwnh7sa9/4/). My guess is that there are additional properties being added via SquareSpace like a float on the buttons or `text-align: left;` being applied somewhere, etc. Did you inspect the DOM and work through the hierarchy to check styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked above about checking the DOM tree for styles causing the left align, like a float on the buttons. Given your [example](http://ns314.com/addthis-demo.html), there is a float on the buttons. The exact CSS is:

```
.addthis_default_style .addthis_separator,
.addthis_default_style .at4-icon, 
.addthis_default_style .at300b,
.addthis_default_style .at300bo, 
.addthis_default_style .at300bs,
.addthis_default_style .at300m {
    float: left;
}
```

Overwrite that style with `float: none;`  and then add `text-align: center;` to the parent div container which has the classes `addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style`. The buttons will then center.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I had to use `float: none !important;` for it to work.

Comment: Pleased I found this.  I was pulling out my hair!  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case AddThis decides to add more classes that begin in a similar fashion (with "at") I changed it to this:

```
.addthis_default_style .addthis_separator,
.addthis_default_style [class^="at"] {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```